# Adding Horizontal lines before and after listings frame

Tags: listings, line

I have a listing, and I would like to add a `hline` before and after the listing. Using the `frames` style parameter do not work as intended for two reasons: 1. I want to keep a left bar as a separator from numbering and the source code; and 2. There is no space between the frame top/bottom line and the left one.

The sample code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lstdefinestyle{CEE}{language=C, frame=l,  numbers=left,  numbersep=1em,  xleftmargin=2em} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[style=CEE, caption={Hello world}]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

That gives us:

[image]

But I wish a `\hline` that should fill the entire `\textwidth`, not only the frame width, as in (GIMP Edited)

[image]

Pay attention that spacing and line width are not correct since is just a gimp edit. The idea is the same spacing found in `table` environment. As:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I used the package `tcolorbox` to obtain the lines.  You can modify the options of the environment `tmpbox` to suit your needs.  There is one problem though; I don't think it is possible to define a new environment that puts together the `tmpbox` and the `lstlisting`.  So you have to call `tmpbox` each time explicitly.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\newenvironment{tmpbox}{%
  \tcolorbox[%
  empty,
  parbox=false,
  noparskip,
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  frame hidden,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=white,
  left=-.5ex, % right=-4pt,
  before skip=.1ex plus 2pt,
  after skip=1ex plus 2pt,
  overlay unbroken and last={%
    \draw ($(frame.north west)+(0, -6ex)$)
    -- +(1\textwidth, 0);
    \draw ($(frame.south west)+(0, 2ex)$)
    -- +(1\textwidth, 0);    
  }]
}{\endtcolorbox}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{CEE}{%
  frame=l, language=C, numbers=left, numbersep=1em, xleftmargin=2em
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\large\bfseries
  Adding horizontal lines about listings
\end{center}


% See \verb|https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings|.

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tmpbox}
  \begin{lstlisting}[style=CEE, caption={Hello world with hlines}]
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
  }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tmpbox}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{lstlisting}[style=CEE, caption={Hello world}]
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
  }
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: does `tcolorbox` needs `tikz`? or is just for `tikz-calc` ?

Comment: TikZ is needed since we use the instruction overlay unbroken and last.